# two array's union in java not getting desired result

Tags: java

the arguments are {1,2,3} and {2,3,4} of the function. the output should be {1,2,3,4}. I cant understand what i'm doing wrong here.
the output i get is {1,1,2,4,0,0}..
 Please help, thank you

```
void test(int x[],int y[]){
        int i =0;
        int j= 0;
        int f =0;
        int total = x.length+ y.length;
        int a[];
        a = new int[total];
        while(i<x.length && j<y.length){
            if(x[i]<y[j]){
                a[f] = x[i];
                i++;
                f++;
            }else if(x[i]>y[j]){
                a[f] = y[j];
                j++;
                f++;
            }else{
                a[f] = x[j];
                i++;
                j++;
                f++;
            }
        }
        while(i<x.length){
            a[f] = x[i];
            i++;
            f++;
        }
        while(j<y.length){
            a[f] = y[j];
            j++;
            f++;
        }

        for(int w=0;w<a.length;w++){
            System.out.print(a[w]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }



    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `Set` class for this?

Comment: i was asked not to use any classes and predefined functions

Comment: is the type of loop important ?

Comment: no, i can use any loop

Comment: but whats wrong in using while here?

Comment: In the else-clauses set a[f] = y[j], not a[f] = x[j].

Comment: Sorry for being stupid

Comment: I'm a big fan of using single letter variables in a small scope where there aren't many other variables, but this scope has many single letter variables which is what confused you to use them incorrectly. I recommend renaming your variables to something more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this Page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-and-intersection-of-two-sorted-arrays-2/

```
// Java program to find union of 
// two sorted arrays 

class FindUnion 
{ 
    /* Function prints union of arr1[] and arr2[] 
    m is the number of elements in arr1[] 
    n is the number of elements in arr2[] */
    static int printUnion(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n) 
    { 
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    while (i < m && j < n) 
    { 
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) 
        System.out.print(arr1[i++]+" "); 
        else if (arr2[j] < arr1[i]) 
        System.out.print(arr2[j++]+" "); 
        else
        { 
        System.out.print(arr2[j++]+" "); 
        i++; 
        } 
    } 

    /* Print remaining elements of 
        the larger array */
    while(i < m) 
    System.out.print(arr1[i++]+" "); 
    while(j < n) 
    System.out.print(arr2[j++]+" "); 

    return 0; 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int arr1[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}; 
        int arr2[] = {2, 3, 5, 7}; 
        int m = arr1.length; 
        int n = arr2.length; 
        printUnion(arr1, arr2, m, n); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: i already tried it, but i want values to be stored in arrays, so i can sort it later,

Comment: maybe the second example on the ref page is better a1 {1, 2, 2, 2, 3} , a2 {2, 3, 4, 5} out = 1 2 3 4 5.

Comment: actually this is my code, would be very helpful if you look into it

Comment: from the second example the output i am getting is 1,2,2,2,3,4,5

Comment: in the code i have first sorted both arrays, then i have removed duplicate elements, not removed exactly, just displayed the right ones. then all is getting out of control in test method